# Using pattern matching in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a some strings which have the pattern

```
word(word-number, word-number)
```

I would like to use a regular expression to extract the 3 words and the 2 numbers.

I am currently using this

```
    String pattern = "(.+?) (\\() (.+?)(-) (\\d+?) (,) (.+?) (-) (\\d+?) (\\))";
    String a = string.replaceAll(pattern, "$1");
    String b = string.replaceAll(pattern, "$3");
    String c = string.replaceAll(pattern, "$5");
    String d = string.replaceAll(pattern, "$7");
    String e = string.replaceAll(pattern, "$9");
```

But no avail any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to get rid of the whitespace in your regex.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern to match `word(word-number, word-number)` is simply

```
String regex = "(\\D+)\\((\\D+)-(\\d+), (\\D+)-(\\d+)\\)";
```

You are using excess spaces and capturing groups in yours.

Now, to extract each individual capture group, use the `Pattern` API.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(string);
m.matches();
String a = m.group(1), b = m.group(2), c = m.group(3), d = m.group(4), e = m.group(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do as @Marko says to extract capture groups.
Then just rearrange the regex slightly.

```
 #  "^(.+?)\\((.+?)-(\\d+?),\\s*(.+?)-(\\d+?)\\)$"

 ^                      # BOL
 ( .+? )                # (1), word
 \(                     #  '('
 ( .+? )                # (2), word
 -                      # '-'
 ( \d+? )               # (3), number
 , \s*                  # ', '
 ( .+? )                # (4), word
 -                      # '-
 ( \d+? )               # (5), numbr
 \)                     # ')'
 $                      # EOL
```